# How I change textviews textsize for different device automatically?

Tags: android, textview

I add two different devices screen.

First, 10.1 inch:

everything is normal!!!:
[image: everything is normal!!!]

But the smaller screens, for example 5 inc.

There is problem..:
[image: There is problem..]

I want textviews textsize automatically changes the best size for the each screen. How can I manage?

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) platform? Language? Framework? Code? How are we supposed to help if you don't say a word about what you did?

Comment: sory my english :( i add two pictures for telll my problem. İ want that the text sizes changes  for different device automaticly. if i make text size 200dp etc. textview slide bottom and some part of textview is happening invisible

Answer (score -1):

You can use dimens.xml 
like that. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRp47.png)

set your basic size and set other dimens.xml

```
<resources>
 <dimen name="dp48_w360">51.200005dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="dp13_w360">13.866668dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="dp7_w360">7.466667dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="dp10_w360">10.666667dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="dp0_5_w360">0.53333336dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="dp26_w360">28.000002dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="dp15_w360">16.0dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="dp22_5_w360">24.000002dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="dp45_w360">48.000004dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="dp133_w360">141.86667dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

or You'd better using sp.

for more detail, refer to https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23962581)

Comment: @Sukhi ok I did. Thanks for your advice.